Can exterior trim 2x4 be use for stud in a shed?
I got 1 lot (about 70 counts) of exterior 2x4 primed trim. I am building a shed and I was wondering can I use these as studs? The shed will have to pass electrical inspection since I am pulling power from the house.
The trim are from Dakeryn their Premium SPF Fascia line. And they are solid wood all the way (at least claimed and seems to be)
Dakeryn SPF page


How can you prove they are not fingerjointed?

@DelphicOracle The texture side is the face side. The back side is usually rough as in not finished well at all. The different pieces that make up finger joint material can usually be seen there.

Trim wood does not need to meet structural rating.  It would probably not pass a home build inspection.  A shed is usually not inspected as well/to high standards, but does depend on local weather(snow, wind) loads expected.

The product literature states that this product is suitable for finishing trim applications, therefore structural applications are not included.
